# SQL to calculate the overall total and sub total number but unique

Tags: sql, group-by, count, google-bigquery, partition

I have an example data as below.

[image]

I want to calculate user count per city and user count per country.

Here's what I want:

[image]

How can I implement it in BigQuery as simple as possible?

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use analytical function as follows:

```
select distinct country, city,
       count(distinct username) over (partition by country, city) as distinct_users_per_city,
       count(distinct username) over (partition by country) as distinct_users_per_country
  from your_Table t
```

Comment: I like this answer, looks very simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I want to calculate user count per city and user count per country

I feel like `Jessie` from `Tokyo` and `Jessie` from `Okinawa` are two different users and needs to be counted as such for country count! Same goes for `Jack` from `Chicago` and `Jack` from `New York`!

Below code does this

```
select distinct country, city,
  count(distinct username) over (partition by country, city) as user_count_per_city,
  count(distinct username || '|' || city) over(partition by country) as user_count_per_country
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

which is different from yours (expected/presented in the question) for above described reason

Comment: Although your output is different from my answer, but every time I can learn a lot from your answers, this time I have another valuable lesson. Thank you so so much!

Comment: sure. consider voting up the answer then :o)